# Adding OneSignal dependency causing Activity Reload

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I have implemented OneSignal in my app which is causing the Launch Activity to reload on the very first App Launch. I even removed the OneSignal initialization code and found out that just adding the OneSignal dependency in app's build.gradle is causing the issue. The weird thing is that it happens on the very first app launch and not on subsequent launches.

On investigation, I found out that some Configuration change is happening which is causing the activity to reload. By Overriding OnPause method of apps Launch Activity and calling getChangingConfigurations(); I got the int value of the config that has changed to be -2147483648 . On further investigation, I found out that the said constant value relates to SIGNAL_STRENGTH_UNSPECIFIED which can be found out [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#SIGNAL_STRENGTH_UNSPECIFIED) . Now I am out of ideas how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the Log https://hastebin.com/osefigixun.apache